GCP: Cloud Tasks cannot trigger Cloud Run Function using the authenticated client
I followed the vercel tutorial to authenticate Cloud Tasks in an API route:
let client: CloudTasksClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  client = new CloudTasksClient({
    projectId: GCP_PROJECT_ID,
    credentials: {
      type: 'external_account',
      audience: `//iam.googleapis.com/projects/${GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/providers/${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_PROVIDER_ID}`,
      subject_token_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt',
      token_url: 'https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token',
      service_account_impersonation_url: `https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}:generateAccessToken`,
      subject_token_supplier: {
        // Use the Vercel OIDC token as the subject token
        getSubjectToken: getVercelOidcToken,
      },
    },
  });
} else {
  // You need to be authenticated with your google account using gcloud auth login
  client = new CloudTasksClient();
}

I can successfully enqueue tasks, but the problem lies with the Cloud Function handler. Even though the impersonated service account has the Cloud Run Invoker Role, the queue isn’t able to send requests to the handler, and I don’t understand why. Here’s what I have to do to make it work:
        const authClient = new GoogleAuth({ ... });
        const idTokenClient = await authClient.getIdTokenClient(CLASSIFIER_HANDLER_URL);
        const idToken = await idTokenClient.idTokenProvider.fetchIdToken(CLASSIFIER_HANDLER_URL);
        for await (const conversation of aggregate) {
            const id = `${conversation._id.questionnaire_id}_${conversation._id.user_id}_${conversation._id.question_project_id}`
            const task: protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.ITask = {
                name: `projects/${GCP_PROJECT_ID}/locations/${CLASSIFIER_LOCATION}/queues/${CLASSIFIER_QUEUE}/tasks/${id}`,
                httpRequest: {
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}`,
                    },
                    httpMethod: 'POST',
                    url: CLASSIFIER_HANDLER_URL,
                    body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
                      conversation: conversation,
                      topics,
                      lang,
                    })).toString('base64'),
                },
            }
            requests.push(client.createTask({ parent, task }))
        }

However, I don’t understand why I have to authenticate twice. I also wonder what would happen if a task fails for a long time. Would the fetched token expire in such a case?
[edit]: I just notice that the deployed version doesn't work. It seems that I can't obtain an id token using the GoogleAuth above:

Cannot fetch ID token in this environment, use GCE or set the
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to a service
account credentials JSON file


It's a bad practice to hardcode the id token in the task itself. It's insecure (if someone read the task list and content). And if you delay your task execution (or if there is many retry) after 1H your id token expire.
It's better to use the Cloud Task authentication mechanism. You have the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-create-http-task-with-token#cloud_tasks_create_http_task_with_token-nodejs
You have to add the in the oidc token part your service account email. Grant the service account the permission to invoke your endpoint (Cloud Run Invoker for instance).
If Cloud Task, and the service account that you use are in the same project, no extra permission are required.
Then, let the Cloud Task magic happen: when the task if trigger, it automatically generate an IDToken and update the header, and then invoke the Cloud Run.
